# How to find out number of distinct rows when using XSLT data view web aprt

Tags: sharepoint-designer, xslt, xslt-list-view-web-part

Hi i know that we can find number of rows in XSLT data view web part by using this expression

```
<xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
<xsl:value-of select="count($Rows[@Age])" />
```

Where Age is a column in the List.

Can any one help me to find out distinct number of rows in the same way.
I am using XSLT 1.0
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What exactly is it you want to find? The total count of rows or the total count of rows with a value in a specific column?

Comment: I am trying to find out total number of distinct rows for a specified column in a list (Where Age is a column in the list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i am able to find out answer to my problem.

This is the one that is working for me

```
<xsl:key match="Row" name="keyy" use="@Age"></xsl:key>
<xsl:value-of select= "count(//Rows/Row[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyy', @Age)[1])])"/>
```

Where Age is a column which will be having unique values.